# How to add an attachement to an email (not stored in file disk)

Tags: javascript, outlook

I want to open outlook with an attachement (zip) using Javascript.
It's working fine if the file in in some directory in the computer client.

```
this.sendEmail = function (zip) {
    try {

        var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
        var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
        var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0); // value 0 = MailItem
        theMailItem.to = ('test@gmail.com');
        theMailItem.Subject = ('test');
        theMailItem.Body = ('test');
        theMailItem.Attachments.Add(zip);
        theMailItem.display();
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
};
```

But What I want to do is to add the file that I have alredy in memory

```
    this.SenddZip = function (docDescription, fileName) {
    var zip = new JSZip();

    for (var i = 0; i < docDescription.length; i++) {
        var doc = docDescription[i];
        zip.file(doc.core_documenttitle + doc.core_fileextension, doc.fileBase64, { base64: true });
    }
    Utils.sendEmail(zip);
    // Generate the zip file asynchronously
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
        .then(function (content) {
            // Force down of the Zip file
            var name = "documents";
            if (fileName) {
                name = fileName;
            }
           // location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
             saveAs(content, name + ".zip");
            Utils.sendEmail(xxxxxxxx);

        });

};
```

If their is no solution for this : 
Is their a way to download the document without the confirmation dialog ?
saveAs ask always for confirmation before to store the file.

Thank you

Comment: Is this inside a web page? Outlook cannot read from your web page, the data in the browser is sandboxed for security reasons. P.S. using ActiveX to control your Outlook instance from the browser is going to be a comparatively short-term solution, since ActiveX is deprecated and no longer being developed. It will not work in any browser except IE11 and below, and support for IE11 (the only supported version) will come to an end when support for Windows 10 ends. You've got a few years, but your solution will not last forever.

Comment: Thank you for the great comment ! I will look for another solution for the requirement...  Is their a way to download the document without the confirmation dialog ? saveAs ask always for confirmation before to store the file.

Comment: It depends entirely on the user's browser settings. Don't forget, a web page (something on a remote server, whose origin might be uncertain) is asking to change something on the user's machine. So from a security point of view it's correct that the computer doesn't automatically trust the web page, and instead asks the user to confirm whether they're happy to receive this data. The user can choose to suppress that warning if they wish.

Comment: Some browsers (e.g. I think Chrome does this from memory) suppress them by default but have a specific place where all downloads go and are visible, and also it does some security checks e.g. does virus scan, and warns about executables, and some types of file it just plain refuses to accept. So like I say, it's all down to the browser, and none of it is within your control as the website developer.